# What are the drawbacks of using an algorithm that is not backwards stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-analysis

(This question might be legitimately crossposted to stackoverflow or mathoverflow or programming StackExchanges.)

## Preface

I'm reading this paper on solving linear systems of equations `Ax = b` using an explicit inverse (held by conventional wisdom as a big no-no): Druinsky & Toledo, "How accurate is inv(A)*b?", http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6035

It asserts that in non-pathological cases, calculating a solution to `Ax=b` via `inv(A)*b` using the explicit inverse of a matrix produces solutions that are as accurate and as stable as preferred methods such as via LU factorization. It goes on to describe exactly which situations using "inv" might be *bad* (technically, when the right-hand side, `b`, is nearly orthogonal to the subspace spanned by left-singular vectors of `A` with low singular values). Even in these cases, the paper asserts, the solutions of `inv(A)*b` are *as accurate* as preferred methods, they're just not backwards stable.

## Question

My question is: what are the specific drawbacks of using an algorithm that isn't guaranteed to be backwards stable? If all I wanted was some solutions to `Ax=b`, and I was guaranteed accurate results, does it matter that the solutions aren't backwards stable? Is there any specific examples of when it's ok to use an accurate but backwards-unstable algorithm?

## Furthermore

My experimentation in Matlab/Octave shows me that the difference between a backwards-unstable and -stable algorithm is that slight perturbations to the solution result in bigger errors when going back through the linear system:

```
norm(A * (inv(A) * b) - b)
```

is much larger than

```
norm(A * (A \ b) - b)
```

for a "bad" `b` (nearly orthogonal to the subspace of left-singular vectors with low singular values), where `\` solves linear systems using Gaussian elimination (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). The solutions themselves have the same accuracy, i.e., `norm(A\b - true_x)` is about the same as `norm(inv(A)*b - true_x)`.

I can imagine that in the case that

1. I *only* cared about getting a solution to `Ax=b` and
2. knew I would *never* propagate the solution back through `A`,

could I justify using `inv(A)` when I didn't want to bother checking that `b` isn't "bad", i.e., without ensuring that the solution was backwards-stable. To me, this doesn't seem worth it, even without the speed and convenience advantages of using LU or Cholesky or QR decompositions.

Comment: You might ask the moderators to migrate your question to scicomp.stackexchange.com.  I think where you care most about backward stability is when solving stiff ordinary differential equations.  This query turned up some stuff that might (or might not) be relevant to you: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=backward+stability+is%3Aquestion.

Answer (score 1):

Sivan Toledo responded to my query with the following:

> In general, the significance and the broad-context meaning of
>   mathematical results is a matter of opinion and debate, so perhaps not
>   every researcher would agree to our explanation below.
>
> In most of the literature, backward stability is a technical and/or
>   analytic tool that makes it relatively easy to prove that an algorithm
>   produces accurate results (or to bound the inaccuracy). In these
>   contexts, the user of the numerical method worries about accuracy, not
>   about backward stability, and the numerical analyst uses backward
>   stability just as a mechanism to prove the bound that the user cares
>   about.
>
> (The analysis in our paper proves accuracy without relying directly on
>   backward stability, but this is atypical.)
>
> When an algorithm is backward stable, the user gets not only a bound
>   on the magnitude of the error, but also an estimate of its direction;
>   it lies in the direction of right singular vectors that correspond to
>   small singular values (for the case of solving linear equations). In
>   many cases this is completely meaningless to the user.
>
> Backward stability may be meaningful to the end user if the parameters
>   of the problem (say the coefficients of a linear equation) are only
>   known approximately, say because they are measured or estimated using
>   some limited-accuracy physical instrument. In some of these cases it
>   may be good for the user to know that the output she/he got is an
>   exact solution to a nearby problem.

I'd still like to better understand theoretically what the drawbacks of using `inv(A)*b` are when `b` is "bad". That is, if the solution using `inv` is as accurate as with a "better" algorithm, what really matters. (This is hinted at computationally in my question: the projection matrix `A * inv(A' * A) * A'` is at least unreliable.)